# In Information Retrieval, are permuterm indexes $hello and hello$ the same?

Tags: information-retrieval

Basically the question above!
Was reading university slides on Permuterm indexes and found that certain lecturers omits the permuterm index hello$ (ie. treating $hello as the same index as hello$) while certain lectures treats them as distinct indexes.